# What is the meaning of having a certain number of OpenCL work-items into a CPU?

Tags: opencl

I'm trying tu understand why I could have more work-items in a CPU than a GPU in one dimension.

PLATFORM 0 DEVICE 0

== CPU ==

```
DEVICE_VENDOR: Intel
DEVICE NAME: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF PARALLAEL COMPUTE UNITS: 4
MAXIMUM DIMENSIONS FOR THE GLOBAL/LOCAL WORK ITEM IDs: 3
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF WORK-ITEMS IN EACH DIMENSION: (1024 1 1  )
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF WORK-ITEMS IN A WORK-GROUP: 1024
```

PLATFORM 0 DEVICE 1

== GPU ==

```
DEVICE_VENDOR: Intel Inc.
DEVICE NAME: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF PARALLAEL COMPUTE UNITS: 48
MAXIMUM DIMENSIONS FOR THE GLOBAL/LOCAL WORK ITEM IDs: 3
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF WORK-ITEMS IN EACH DIMENSION: (256 256 256  )
MAXIMUM NUMBER OF WORK-ITEMS IN A WORK-GROUP: 256
```

The above is the result of my test code to print the information of the actual hardware that the OpenCL framework can use.

I really do not understand why the value of 1024 in the Maximum number of work-items in the CPU section. What is the real meaning of having that amount of work-items?

Answer (score 0):

CPUs are more general purpose than GPUs. Their OpenCL implementation looks like serialized(but interleaved on instructions) for workgroups since each compute unit is a physical core to issue workgroups as a whole. Since they are serialized/interleaved, they rely on instructions-in-flight. CPUs have 100-200 instructions in-flight and if those instructions are AVX/SSE, then you can expect 800-1600 scalar data operations in-flight. This is well within range of 1024 workitems per workgroup, if OpenCL implementation is vectorized under the hood.

Since GPUs use massive thread-level-parallelism to fill pipelines to have more instructions-in-flight, they don't need as much ILP as CPUs so they can work fine with just 256 threads per workgroup and these threads run in parallel. Thread-level-parallelism fills pipelines easier than instruction-level-parallelism. Intel has 7-way, Nvidia 16-way, Amd 40-way thread-level-parallelism, for each pipeline. Each subslice of Iris6100 has (8 EUs) 64 pipelines. 64 pipelines x 7 means it can have multiple workgroups in-flight too, just like Nvidia and Amd GPUs. Probably having more threads/workitems per workgroup doesn't yield more performance for that iGPU and having more than 1024 threads per workgroup doesn't yield more performance for that CPU.

CPU also has 256kB L2 cache for compute unit which may be another limiting factor on maximum 1024 workitems per workgroup for saving states of each workitem efficiently.

As an image processing example:

- You can divide and conquer an image by having 32x32 patches of it, on CPU(1024 threads). But this needs re-computation of 2D indices in kernel since CPU supports 1D kernel.
- You can divide and conquer an image by having 16x16 patches of it, on iGPU (256 threads).
- 256x1 on iGPU
- 1024x1 on CPU
- 8x8x4 on iGPU
- 1x256x1 on iGPU
- 1x1x256 on iGPU
- but not 1x1024x1 on CPU

They are the number of workitems per workgroup and generally they are a fraction of maximum allowed in-flight workitems per compute unit.
For this image processing example, up to several thousands of pixels can be in-flight per compute unit or up to 50k-100k pixels in-flight for a high-end GPU.

Having only 1 on other dimensions for CPU (imo) is originated from CPU's OpenCL implementation being an emulation. It doesn't have hardware to accelerate computation of thread-id values for other dimensions. But GPUs probably have this kind of support on hardware so that they can have more dimensions without decreasing performance as 1D kernel on CPU has to compute some modulos and divisions to emulate 2nd and 3rd dimensions which is a bottleneck for simple kernels.

If CPUs had emulated 2nd and 3rd dimensions too, there would be some modulos and divisions going on background with further slow-downs inside kernel if developers flatten a 3d kernel into 1d indices unknowingly. But GPUs may not even be computing modules under the hood. They could be just some lookup tables as fast as registers or some other fast accessed constants.

This is just a limitation per workgroup. You can launch many workgroups per kernel launch so it shouldn't affect the maximum image size to process in different devices like CPU or GPU or iGPU. Each image is processed by multiple workgroups for tiling from 1x1x1 to 32x32x1 or some other size.